# jetty, war deploy

Tags: java, jetty, war

We are using jetty to deploy our war in our application. It is all working fine with jre-jdk 1.6.0_06 , u23, u31 but in our customer's system, application throws the below error for all jre-jdk 1.6 u6,u23,u31 when extracting the war to /var/tmp. /var/tmp dir has default permissions. I mean the permission of /var/tmp is `drwxrwxrwt` 
Heap size arguments are `-Xms128m -Xmx1024m`

OS : **Solaris sparc 5.10**.

I am not sure about memory size but I think it is not less than 4gb.

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.TagLibConfiguration.configureWebApp(TagLibConfiguration.java:171)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1215)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:500)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:147)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:161)
     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:147)
     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:117)
     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:210)
     at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
```

Any idea on that?

Comment: this looks less like an unpacking of the war file issue and more of the processing of the contents of the war file itself.  see the TagLibConfiguration class: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-webapp/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/TagLibConfiguration.java#L171

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that JVM considers to be a temp directory is not accessible due to not having permission to write. See [Temporary Directories](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Temporary+Directories) and [Bug](http://mifosforge.jira.com/browse/MIFOS-4765)

Comment: Actually, it has. As I wrote in question , /var/tmp directory has drwxrwxrwxt permission. I will try to redirect tmp dir with using -Djava.io.tmpdir